# Incomplete type is not allowed in a class, but is allowed in a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, forward-declaration

The following is invalid code:

```
struct foo {
    struct bar;
    bar x;        // error: field x has incomplete type
    struct bar{ int value{42}; };
};

int main() { return foo{}.x.value; }
```

This is quite clear, as `foo::bar` is considered incomplete at the point where `foo::x` is defined.

However, there seems to be a "workaround" which makes the same class definition valid:

```
template <typename = void>
struct foo_impl {
    struct bar;
    bar x;        // no problems here
    struct bar{ int value{42}; };
};

using foo = foo_impl<>;

int main() { return foo{}.x.value; }
```

This [works](https://godbolt.org/g/8vjFNk) with all major compilers.
I have three questions about this:

1. Is this indeed valid C++ code, or just a quirk of the compilers?
2. If it is valid code, is there a paragraph in the C++ standard that deals with this exception?
3. If it is valid code, why is the first version (without `template`) considered invalid? If the compiler can figure out the second option, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't be able to figure out the first one.

---

If I add an explicit specialization for `void`:

```
template <typename = void>
struct foo_impl {};

template<>
struct foo_impl<void> {
    struct bar;
    bar x;        // error: field has incomplete type
    struct bar{ int value{42}; };
};

using foo = foo_impl<>;

int main() { return foo{}.x.value; }
```

It once again [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/g/3NsNhA).

Comment: Yes, there are template specializations here. Specializations do not have to be explicit. `foo` is a specialization of `foo_impl`

Comment: @Barry but then why does it work with "implicit" specialization, and not with "explicit" specialization?

Comment: Well, with the explicit specialization it's "obviously" wrong but as-is it's not "obviously" wrong?

Comment: @Barry, not a very "legal" argument :) But I think I have an idea why it might be happening. In your answer, one of the conditions for this behavior is: "if the context from which the specialization is referenced depends on a template parameter". In explicit specialization, the context does not depend on a template parameter, so the rule of instantiating `foo_impl<void>::bar` immediately before the definition of `foo_impl<void>` does not apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real answer might be ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, but it's probably currently okay because templates are magical, but it may be more explicitly not okay pending some other core issue resolutions.

First, the main problem of course is [[class.mem]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-14):

> Non-static data members shall not have incomplete types.

This is why your non-template example is ill-formed. However, according to [[temp.point]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#4):

> For a class template specialization, a class member template specialization, or a specialization for a class member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another template specialization, if the context from which the specialization is referenced depends on a template parameter, and if the specialization is not instantiated previous to the instantiation of the enclosing template, **the point of instantiation is immediately before the point of instantiation of the enclosing template**. Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately precedes the namespace scope declaration or definition that refers to the specialization.

Which suggests that `foo_impl<void>::bar` is instantiated *before* `foo_impl<void>`, and hence it's complete at the point where the non-static data member of type `bar` is instantiated. So maybe it's okay.

*However*, core language issues [1626](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626) and [2335](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2335) deal with not-exactly-the-same-but-still-quite-similar issues regarding completeness and templates, and both point to desiring to make the template case more consistent with the non-template case.

What does all of this mean when viewed as a whole? I'm not sure.

Comment: It says "if the specialization is implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another template from within another template specialization" Do we really have that? "if the context from which the specialization is referenced depends on a template parameter" We don't have that. Correct?

Comment: @Barry  welcome back! :) The only problem I see here is that there is no template specialization anywhere in my example (only default arguments != specialization). I would have had to write `template<> foo_impl<void> { /* specialization */ };` somewhere to have this scenario.

Comment: Funny thing is, when I _do_ specialize it for `void`, it once again fails to compile :/ I'll update the question to include this.

Comment: @Goran The standard uses specialization in multiple contexts, unfortunately. It can be confusing. `vector<int> v;` leads to instantiating a specialization of the class template `vector`

Comment: @Barry yes, didn't know that, the standard clearly says it in [\[temp.spec\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#4). Maybe add this to your answer, to make it clearer for other people reading this.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm starting to think we have this situation here: "if the specialization is implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another template specialization" -> the specialization `foo_impl<void>::bar` is referenced from within the specialization `foo_impl<void>` (which happens in `foo{}.x.value`) when defining the variable `foo_impl<void>::x`.  "if the context from which the specialization is referenced depends on a template parameter" -> the context (the definition of `foo_impl` class template) depends on the template parameter, here substituted by `void`.

Comment: I will (conditionally) accept this one for now, as it is the most plausible explanation we have - this will make it the first answer to appear and hopefully steer other people towards confirming / disproving it.

Comment: @Barry `bar` is not dependent, so [temp.point] can't apply. You can specialize bar, but that doesn't mean that it is dependent.

Comment: @Rakete1111 `bar` is dependent http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#type-9.3

Answer (score 5):

I think this example is explicitly allowed by

> **17.6.1.2 Member classes of class templates [temp.mem.class]**
>
> 1
>   A member class of a class template may be defined outside the class template definition in which it is declared.
>   [Note: The member class must be defined before its first use that requires an instantiation (17.8.1) For example,
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>   class B;
> };
>
> A<int>::B* b1; // OK: requires A to be defined but not A::B
> template<class T> class A<T>::B { };
> A<int>::B b2; // OK: requires A::B to be defined
> ```
>
> —end note ]

This should [work](https://godbolt.org/g/qRAqcQ) fine too:

```
template <typename = void>
struct foo_impl {
    struct bar;
    bar x;        // no problems here
};

template<typename T>
struct foo_impl<T>::bar{ int value{42}; };

using foo = foo_impl<>;

int main()
{
    return foo{}.x.value;
}
```

Comment: So now that the comments have been wiped, I'll again make the point that this quote merely states *where* you can define `bar`. It doesn't say anything about whether or not you can have a member `bar` before it's defined (wherever it ends up being defined).

Answer (score 0):

### More details about the accepted answer

I am not sure that the accepted answer is the correct explanation, but it is the most plausible one for now. Extrapolating from that answer, here are the aswers to my original questions:

1. Is this indeed valid C++ code, or just a quirk of the compilers? [ **It is valid code.** ]
2. If it is valid code, is there a paragraph in the C++ standard that deals with this exception? [ **[[temp.point]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#4)** ]
3. If it is valid code, why is the first version (without `template`) considered invalid? If the compiler can figure out the second option, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't be able to figure out the first one. [ **Because C++ is weird** - it handles class templates differently than classes (you could have probably guessed this one). ]

### Some more explanations

#### What *seems* to be happening

When instantiating `foo{}` in `main` the compiler instantiates an (implicit) specialization for `foo_impl<void>`. This specialization references `foo_impl<void>::bar` on line 4 (`bar x;`). The context is within a template definition so it depends on a template parameter, and the specialization `foo_impl<void>::bar` is obviously not previously instantiated, so all the preconditions for **[temp.point]/4** are fulfilled, and the compiler generates the following intermediate (pseudo)code:

```
template <typename = void>
struct foo_impl {
    struct bar;
    bar x;        // no problems here
    struct bar{ int value{42}; };
};

using foo = foo_impl<>;

// implicit specialization of foo_impl<void>::bar, [temp.point]/4
$ struct foo_impl<void>::bar {
$     int value{42};
$ };
// implicit specialization of foo_impl<void> 
$ struct foo_impl<void> {
$     struct bar;
$     bar x;   // bar is not incomplete here
$ };
int main() { return foo{}.x.value; }
```

#### About *specialization*

As per [[temp.spec]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#4):

> A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized.

so the call to `foo{}.x.value` in the original implementation with templates qualifies as a specialization (this was something new to me).

### About the version with explicit specialization

The version with explicit specialization does not compile as it seems that:

> if the context from which the specialization is referenced depends on a template parameter

no longer holds, so the rule from **[temp.point]/4** does not apply.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again on this, but [temp.point] refers to dependent names. Neither `bar` or `x` is dependent. Yes you can specialize them, but that doesn't mean that it is dependent.

Comment: @Rakete1111 but it's not `bar`, it's `foo_impl<>::bar` ?

Comment: @Swift 3 people here (including me) already tried to explain that, see his answer for his interpretation of the standard (basically, "bar always has the semantics of an empty class so it is not dependent").

Comment: @Swift That doesn't matter. I'm not saying that it's always the same `bar`, but just that for different instantiations of the same template, `bar` has the same definition (but they're not the same). But I'll stop arguing, this is unproductive.

Comment: on 3rd bullet I may add that it isn't really weird. Provided all requirements to templates, fact that order of declaration doesn't affect result of subtitution, the SFINAE paradigm and fact that templates can be recursive and thier implementation is created from context of existing code, that's only way how templates could be implemented without serious quirks. Essentially compiler must do separate pass after translating whole unit. For first version to be valid, compiler have to perform two passes, and there rises One Definition problem.

Answer (score -3):

I'll answer the third part of your question - as IANALL (not a language lawyer).

The code is invalid for the same reason it's invalid to use a function before it has been declared - even though the compiler can figure out what the function's supposed to be by going further down in the same translation unit. And the cases are similar also in the sense that if you happen to have just a declaration with no definition, that's good enough for the compiler, while here you happen to have a template definition before the instantiation.

So the point is: **The language standard mandates that the compiler does not look ahead for you** when you want to define something (and a class template is not a definition of a class).

Comment: Yes, it is clear to me why the compiler would have more problems with the first version of the code - but this is a technical detail of the compiler. The compiler should do whatever the language standard prescribes, not the other way around. This answer seems like "the second example works because the compiler is implemented in a certain way", which would imply that the answer to the first question is "a quirk of the compiler" (in which case question 3 is not relevant).

Comment: @GoranFlegar: I said I'm not a language lawyer. I provided the rationale as I see it.