# Forward declaring all future functions with a template results in ambiguity instead of pairing declaration with definition

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using a c++ idiom that allows defining a common behavior (`GeneralFunction`) that is customized by making it call specific functions (`SpecificFunction`) – switching between them by tag classes (unfortunately I forgot the name of the idiom).

I decided I wanted the SpecificFunctions to have an arbitrary return type. But since we're in c++ I need to declare the identifier in advance before mentioning it in `GeneralFunction`.

Here I hope I'm declaring a SpecificFunction template that will be upon its instantiation a declaration matching a concrete SpecificFunction overload which will be defined below:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
struct ReturnTypeTrick;

template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
inline auto SpecificFunction(Tag, Args&& ... args) -> typename ReturnTypeTrick<Tag, Args...>::type;  // basically saying SpecificFunction returns what it returns
```

the return type is not known until instantiation, but it should not matter now. I just need to to declare the identifier, so that I can use it in `GeneralFunction`

```
template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
struct ReturnTypeTrick {
    using type = decltype(SpecificFunction(Tag(), std::declval<Args>() ...));
};
```

The general function with common behavior:

```
template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
inline auto GeneralFunction (Args&& ... specific_args) {
    // do something common for all implementations

    // this is where the behavior differs
    return SpecificFunction(Tag(), std::forward<Args>(specific_args) ...);
}
```

Default implementation for SpecificFunction I decided to provide:

```
template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
inline bool SpecificFunction(Tag, Args&& ...) {  // default implementation
    return false;
}
```

defining specific behavior functions:

```
struct Algorithm1 {};

inline auto SpecificFunction(Algorithm1, int param1, char param2) {
    return 10;
}


struct Algorithm2 {};

inline auto SpecificFunction(Algorithm2, long param1) {
    return "y";
}

struct Algorithm3 {};



int main() {
    std::cout << GeneralFunction<Algorithm1>(1, 'a') << std::endl;
    std::cout << GeneralFunction<Algorithm2>(1l) << std::endl;  
    /* these somehow work, probably independently on the
   `SpecificFunction` declaration above because my compiler is OK with
   functions not being declared at all. BUT changing these simple
   SpecificFunction definitions into templates – that is line in
   GeneralFunction would look like 
   return SpecificFunction<SomeTemplateArg>(Tag(), std::forward<Args>(specific_args) ...); 
   – and removing the declaration results in undeclared indentifier
   `SpecificFunction`, so I need to be able to declare it */

    std::cout << GeneralFunction<Algorithm3>("wtf this should call the  // default implementation") << std::endl;
    // error: call to 'SpecificFunction' is ambiguous

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename ReturnTypeTrick<Algorithm3, const char*>::type, bool>, "the return type of the generated declaration is correct if you don't see this message");

    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
/scratch_2.cpp:22:12: error: call to 'SpecificFunction' is ambiguous
    return SpecificFunction(Tag(), std::forward<Args>(specific_args) ...);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/scratch_2.cpp:51:18: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'GeneralFunction<Algorithm3, char const (&)[52]>' requested here
    std::cout << GeneralFunction<Algorithm3>("wtf this should call the  // default implementation") << std::endl;
                 ^
/scratch_2.cpp:8:13: note: candidate function [with Tag = Algorithm3, Args
      = <char const (&)[52]>]
inline auto SpecificFunction(Tag, Args&& ... args) -> typename ReturnTypeTrick<Tag, Args...>::type;  // basically saying Spe...
            ^
/scratch_2.cpp:26:7: note: candidate function [with Tag = Algorithm3, Args
      = <char const (&)[52]>]
inline bool SpecificFunction(Tag, Args&& ...) {  // default implementation
```

It seems it cannot match the generated declaration to the definition of the default `SpecificFunction` implementation.

You can see the generated declaration is the same (they call it error: ambiguous) as the definition header. That's funny, because that's exactly the thing – that identity – based on which I thought the declaration and definition was paired.

Also I tried changing the header of `// default implementation` SpecificFunction to

```
template <typename Tag>
inline bool SpecificFunction(Tag, ...) {  // default implementation
    return false;
}
```

but then I get a linker error instead:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ReturnTypeTrick<Algorithm3, char const (&) [52]>::type SpecificFunction<Algorithm3, char const (&) [52]>(Algorithm3, char const (&&&) [52])", referenced from:
      auto GeneralFunction<Algorithm3, char const (&) [52]>(char const (&&&) [52]) in scratch_2-b3bb4f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that the return type is a part of the function signature of a function template specialization.

Thus, the compiler sees two overloads that match `Tag = Alogirthm3`, which (may) differ in their return types:

```
// (A)
template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
inline auto SpecificFunction(Tag, Args&& ... args)
    -> typename ReturnTypeTrick<Tag, Args...>::type;
```

and

```
// (B)
template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
inline bool SpecificFunction(Tag, Args&& ...);
```

To figure out that they are in fact the same, it has to figure out what is `typename ReturnTypeTrick<Tag, Args...>::type`, which is defined as `decltype(SpecificFunction(Tag(), std::declval<Args>() ...)`, once again leading to the resolution of the `SpecificFunction` overload for `Tag = Algorithm3` (which was the problem that we started with). So, what the code is telling the compiler is:

> (A) and (B) are the same if and only if (A) and (B) are the same.

which is obviously ambiguous. Thus, your return type trick is actually incorrect.

The question is: why do you even need (A) and `ReturnTypeTrick` in the first place? Because of the way template instantiation works (in short, specializations are instantiated lazily, just before the place where they are first needed), you should not need the forward declaration at all. Just remove `ReturnTypeTrick` and (A) altogether and your code will compile.

See [live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5Zrp4h).
Also, the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202718/incomplete-type-is-not-allowed-in-a-class-but-is-allowed-in-a-class-template) might be an interesting read. The setting is not exactly the same as yours, but it does discuss the issue of templates behaving differently than normal functions / classes (complete with references to the C++ standard, as opposed to hand waving used in this answer).

BTW: In case you were wondering why the specializations for `Algorithm1` and `Algorithm2` do not have the same problem, it is because a non-template parameter is a better match in overload resolution than a template parameter, so (A) is immediately discarded as a candidate, before even going through the return type resolution.

Comment: If I remove (A) it works since there is maybe some backward compatibility with C and functions don't have to be declared in advance. BUT in general case (A) can be an explicit template instantiation `return SpecificFunction<SomeTemplateArg>(Tag(), std::forward<Args>(specific_args) ...);` Then I get a compilation error: 'SpecificFunction' was not declared in this scope.  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vSUyi1

Comment: @Adam it has nothing to do with C compatibility, as this situation cannot arise in C, and functions do have to be forward declared in C. The problem with your second version is that the compiler does not know if the `<` and `>` signs should be interpreted as comparisons, or as a template specialization (so it assumes they are comparisons), since `SpecificFunction` was not declared before. This is an unfortunate problem of using `<>` for two distinct things. To work around it, you can rely on automatic template argument deduction to avoid such constructs: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bFiBvl